# Sonar analysis fails with NullPointerException in sonar.log

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

We have been using **Sonar 5.1** under **Java 1.7.0_76** on a Unix system for about a month now on a very large multi-project repository (mostly Java 7, JSP, JS, XML and CSS files).  We have recently noticed that Sonar Runner executions are failing in some cases.  Please see the ERROR from the SonarQube log below.  Some info:

- This is happening with different files in different projects – sometimes a .java file, sometimes a .js file -- but it seems to happen consistently with the same file on each run.
- The file it seems to be asking for does in fact exist in our repository.
- All projects are being analyzed by the same user, which has “See Source Code” permission (actually, Anyone has this permission).

Can you tell us what may be causing these failures, and how we can prevent them?  Thanks!

---

### On the server side (in sonar.log)

```
2015.05.26 02:58:56 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://sonar.era.nih.gov/api/sources/hash?key=PRACS%3Asrc%2Fjava%2Fgov%2Fnih%2Fera%2Fpracs%2Fbeans%2FUploadedDocument.java
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
                at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.copy(CharStreams.java:202) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
                at org.sonar.server.source.ws.HashAction$HashFunction.apply(HashAction.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
                at org.sonar.server.source.ws.HashAction$HashFunction.apply(HashAction.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
                at org.sonar.core.source.db.FileSourceDao.readLineHashesStream(FileSourceDao.java:94) ~[sonar-core-5.1.jar:na]
                at org.sonar.server.source.ws.HashAction.handle(HashAction.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
                at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
                at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:425) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:292) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_18AF0797CD66B4E310384A14E2B9EE369902E67F103261525.__file__(/home/sonarqube/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb:30) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_18AF0797CD66B4E310384A14E2B9EE369902E67F103261525.__file__(/home/sonarqube/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B103261525.__file__(/home/sonarqube/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B103261525.__file__(/home/sonarqube/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
                at …
```

---

### On the client-side (sonar-runner)

The resulting error has the following lines output from sonar-runner (I’ll send the full thing if you need it, but it seems like the real problem was the NPE):

```
[sonar-runner] INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
[sonar-runner] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sonar-runner] Total time: 2:50.798s
[sonar-runner] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution [sonar-runner] org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar [sonar-runner]     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
…
[sonar-runner] Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@1a89552[key=src/java/gov/nih/era/pracs/beans/UploadedDocument.java,path=src/java/gov/nih/era/pracs/beans/UploadedDocument.java,filename=UploadedDocument.java,language=Java]'
[sonar-runner]     at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:104)
…
[sonar-runner] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://sonar.era.nih.gov/api/sources/hash?key=PRACS%3Asrc%2Fjava%2Fgov%2Fnih%2Fera%2Fpracs%2Fbeans%2FUploadedDocument.java]
[sonar-runner]     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:139)
…
[sonar-runner] Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://sonar.era.nih.gov/api/sources/hash?key=PRACS%3Asrc%2Fjava%2Fgov%2Fnih%2Fera%2Fpracs%2Fbeans%2FUploadedDocument.java]. Response code: 500 [sonar-runner]     at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:305)
```

Comment: Could you please execute the following SQL query and send us the result : SELECT line_hashes FROM file_sources INNER JOIN projects on projects.uuid=file_uuid WHERE projects.kee='PRACS:src/java/gov/nih/era/pracs/beans/UploadedDocument.java' ?

Comment: Let me run that query, but on a different problematic file (the PRACS error is not appearing today, which may be the result of the PRACS team deleting and re-creating their Sonar project -- not an option for most other teams)...

Comment: The query returns exactly one row, but the line_hashes column value is a **NULL** CLOB.  On other (ordinary) files it is a CLOB with hex values in it, and on non-existent files it returns no rows.  Please remember that this file does in fact exist, and is non-empty.

Comment: In previous SQ version, have you ever used sonar.importSources=false? I don't know how you manage to reach this state, but you should be able to fix the build by excluding offending file using sonar.exclusions, then run an analysis, then make the file back into the analysis.